# Foursquare venue stats - all in one shot

Tags: api, foursquare, rate-limiting

I have a list of managed venues.

There is a [Venue Stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats) endpoint, which allows me to get statistics for given venue.

Is there an API (existing or planned) for getting such stats for all managed venues, in one shot?

It is easy to hit rate limit if you have more than several hundreds of venues.

And the files output is not what we like - we would prefer to use the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way, currently, to access aggregated stats for a group of venues, but that's a great suggestion and I'll ask the relevant team if they can look into supporting this behavior. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: for all claimed venues, to be specific.

Comment: Note that you *can* get the aggregate check-in stats via the https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/timeseries endpoint, just not the other statistics offered via the venue stats endpoint